# Confusing error message when passing bytes to print with file pointing to a binary file

Tags: python

The documentation for the print function specifies that the input
argument is coerced to string.  However, if bytes are passed and the
file= parameter points to a file open for binary write, the error
message produced is:

```
>>> out = open('temp', 'wb')
>>> print(b'abc', file=out)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: write() argument 1 must be bytes or buffer, not str
```

which is, to say the least, confusing, since I clearly passed print a
bytes object as argument 1.

Comment: I'm not sure what's confusing here. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) explicitly state: *"Since printed arguments are converted to text strings, print() cannot be used with binary mode file objects."*

Answer (score 2):

As you said, `print` coerces its arguments to strings, meaning it is no longer bytes when the write is attempted, but the string `"b'abc'"`. If you're planning to write bytes, `out.write(b'abc')` is one easy way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation in detail [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) it specifies, that:

> Since printed arguments are converted to text strings, print() cannot be
> used with binary mode file objects. For these, use file.write(...) instead.

From here on out, I'm guessing, what your code is doing is:

1. Receives a byte string in the print statement
2. Coerce the byte string into string
3. Tries to write the string to the file
4. The `file.write()` method raises an error, because you are trying to write a string into a file, which is opened in binary write

This can be seen in the error message. Note the err is not coming from the `print()` method it is raised by the `write()` method

Answer (score 0):

Use .write() instead of print(). Don't forget to close file after writing.

```
out = open('temp', 'wb')
out.write(b'abc')
out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to write in a file. This is my example code, try this out.

```
with open('temp','wb') as out:
    out.write(b'abc')
```

It automatically closes the file, no need to close the file again.